# "Cannot Send an Empty Message" when trying to fetch the api into the code

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I've been working on a command which will make the bot exchange currency.
Here is the code:

```
const {
    Client,
    Intents,
    DiscordAPIError,
    Permissions,
    Emoji
} = require('discord.js');
const {
    MessageEmbed
} = require('discord.js');

const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES]
});
const prefix = '-';


client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Floppa is online!');
    client.user.setActivity("-help", {});
    client.user.set
});

client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" ");

    const command = args.shift().toLocaleLowerCase();

const api_url = 'https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_ILS,ILS_USD&compact=ultra&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxx';

    async function getCurrencyILS() 
    { 
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        message.channel.send(data.USD_ILS);
    }

    async function getCurrencyUSD() 
    { 
        const response = await fetch(api_url);
        const data = await response.json();
        message.channel.send(data.ILS_USD);
    }
    //Exchanges currency from USD to ILS, currently working on it!
    if(command == 'excusdils'){
        getCurrencyILS();
    }
    
    //Exchanges currency from ILS to USD, currently working on it!
    if(command == 'excilsusd'){
        getCurrencyUSD();
    }
```

for some reason when I send the command there is some sort of an error:

```
    C:\Users\amare\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\amare\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\amare\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async TextChannel.send (C:\Users\amare\Desktop\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:15) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/channels/923881113955500115/messages',
  code: 50006,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: undefined,
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Thing is, whenever I run this code in the console, it works perfectly (when I change the code inside the function from message.channel.send(data.USD_ILS) to console.log(data.USD_ILS).
Why does that happen?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. When I use something like MongoDB (or another external API). It will output the result to a JSON Format. Not a string. So in order to send it to a channel. You must convert it to a string.

Example :

Discord JS v12 :

```
message.channel.send(data.USD_ILS.toString());
```

Discord JS v13 :

```
message.channel.send({ content: data.USD_ILS.toString() });
```

The reason why it works with `console.log()` is because it was automatically converted to the format that console understand.

Tell me if its work or not.

Comment: It works, thanks!